# Concatenar varios VARCHAR2 + 4000 caracteres

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, clob

Solicito de su colaboración para que me indiquen como puedo concatenar más de un `VARCHAR2` en un `SELECT`, esto `VARCHAR2` tiene un más de 4000 caracteres por lo tanto sale este error:

```
[Error] Execution (31: 64): ORA-01489: el resultado de la concatenación de cadena de caracteres es demasiado largo
```

**Forma 1**

```
SELECT TO_CLOB(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('Ref: ', PRODUCTO), ' '), DETALLE))
  FROM DUAL
```

**Forma 2**

```
SELECT TO_CLOB('Ref: '||PRODUCTO|| ' '|| DETALLE))
  FROM DUAL
```

**Forma 3**

```
SELECT 'Ref: '||PRODUCTO|| ' '||DETALLE ||)
  FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- El tamaño máximo de un un `varchar2` es de 4000 bytes
- El resultado de concatenar varios `varchar2` seguirá siendo un `varchar2`, no existe una promoción automática a un dato de mayor tamaño

La solución, es "promover" alguna de las cadenas a concatenar a un `CLOB`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT TO_CLOB('Ref: ') || PRODUCTO || ' '|| DETALLE
  FROM DUAL
```

En tus pruebas, aunque usas `TO_CLOB()` lo haces siempre luego que el motor evalúa la concatenación de los `varchar2`, de ahí que siempre tienes un error.

Comment: mil gracias, tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 0):

SELECT coalesce(a, '') || coalesce(b, '') FROM foo; el coalesce es tu mejor opcion ya que si es null o algo no vas a tener problema en concatenar y etc. yo utilizo esa. te deje ese ejemplo aplicalo al tuyo

Comment: no me funciona, lo que realmente quiero hacer es concatenar dos `varchar2` de 4000 caracteres, pero el `select` no lo permite ejecutar, según el `coalesce(a, '')` no me soluciona el problema

Comment: dos coalesce en ese caso son. como te puse de ejemplo

Comment: `SELECT 'Ref: '|| coalesce(PRODUCTO, '')|| ' '||coalesce(DETALLE, '') ||)
  FROM DUAL`, me sigue saliendo el mismo error.